# How do I set the view from a KML camera in Cesiumjs?

Tags: datasource, kml, cesiumjs

I have a simple KML file that specifies a camera.

How do I get Cesium to load the KML then fly to the specified camera view?  Also the KML will be updated regularly so how do I get the data source to update and Cesium to fly to the new view on an interval basis?

I have Cesium running on a local web server so it can read the KML from the local file system, and I know the camera has to be rotated from Google's coordinate frame to Cesiums'.

Here's the KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <Camera>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <longitude>-80.215317</longitude>
        <latitude>26.843521</latitude>
        <altitude>306.388825</altitude>
        <heading>48.980423</heading>
        <roll>0.062101</roll>
        <tilt>75.090492</tilt>
    </Camera>
</Document>
</kml>
```

and here's my code so far:

```
<script>

    var My_Altitude;
    var My_Heading;
    var My_Latitude;
    var My_Longitude;
    var My_Roll;
    var My_Tilt;
    var Update_Interval = 60;

    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    var options = {
        camera : viewer.scene.camera,
        canvas : viewer.scene.canvas
    };

    viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('./My_Camera.kml', options)).then(function(dataSource){

        My_Altitude = dataSource.entities.getById('altitude');
        My_Heading = dataSource.entities.getById('heading');
        My_Latitude = dataSource.entities.getById('latitude');
        My_Longitude = dataSource.entities.getById('longitude');
        My_Roll = dataSource.entities.getById('roll');
        My_Tilt = dataSource.entities.getById('tilt');

        viewer.camera.flyTo({
            destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees( My_Longitude, My_Latitude, My_Altitude ),
            orientation : {
                heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Heading ),
                pitch   : Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Tilt - 90.0 ),
                roll    : Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Roll )
            },
            duration : Update_Interval
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

:-)

Comment: If you're creating the KML and consuming it then KML for just the camera is not getting you anything so might as well create JSON file and read in javascript. That way at least it will be simpler to access the fields in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing KML Camera element in the KmlDataSource won't work because the Camera/LookAt elements are not yet supported in Cesium and not present. (See [issue 873](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/873)). If you look at the Object for the data source in web console/debugger you will see entities array is of length 0.

```
My_Tilt = dataSource.entities.getById('tilt'); // returns undefined
```

You need to fetch the KML content and parse the Camera element manually.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "./My_Camera.kml", true);                
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
  {
     var xmlDoc = x.responseXML;
     var camera = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Camera")[0];
     var My_Tilt = camera.getElementsByTagName("tilt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     // ...
  }
};
x.send();
```

The conversion of tilt - 90 to pitch is correct, however, you need to reverse the sign for `roll` to convert from Google Earth to Cesium's representation.

Here is the updated flyTo code:

```
 viewer.camera.flyTo({
            destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees( My_Longitude, My_Latitude, My_Altitude ),
            orientation : {
                heading : Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Heading ),
                pitch   : Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Tilt - 90.0 ),
                roll    : -Cesium.Math.toRadians( My_Roll )
            },
```

If you want to update the KML on an interval then you can create a timer in javascript and re-parse the KML in the timer action.

Comment: Hi. If this answer isn't what you're looking for then please update your answer with more detail and/or post a reply.

Comment: Jason, I apologize for the long delay in responding to you answer.   This was EXACTLY what i needed.   I made the changes to parse the KML content manually and it worked!   Thank you very much for your kind and  professional answer, including the time and effort it took to figure out the issue.   -Alan          P.S. - Since I'm a new poster on StackExchange, it won't let me publicly up vote you answer.

Comment: Ok, no problem!   Thanks again!  :-)